# Different OnMouseEnter events in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following snippet (tweaked by @SpencerWieczorek, thanks):

```js
$('.parent').mouseenter(function(){
  $('.child').fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}


p {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<img src="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />

<div class="child">
<img src="http://maui.hawaii.edu/tlc/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2013/11/testing.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />
</div>
</div>
```

The final goal is to run multiple instances, acting on different elements using OnMouseEnter event in the same page.

I was thinking about a solution but not so sure if It's ok to alterate the parent/child terms. Is that ok to define multiple parent/child parameters (e.g. parent, parent1, parent2, etc also child, child1, child2, etc)?

Comment: I don't get the question, you want to use .mouseenter in different elements ?

Comment: yes, different "pairs" of pictures actionated by .mouseenter like we have above, but in the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `".child"` using `$(this).find('.child')` from the current element. That way it can work with several of them:

```
$('.parent').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).find('.child').fadeToggle();
});
```

```js
$('.parent').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).find('.child').fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}


p {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="parent">
<img src="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />

<div class="child">
<img src="http://maui.hawaii.edu/tlc/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2013/11/testing.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<img src="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />

<div class="child">
<img src="http://maui.hawaii.edu/tlc/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2013/11/testing.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it! thank you so much, I appreciate it. Merry Christmas